# Impose the environment's locale in a Perl block

Tags: perl, encoding, environment-variables, locale

I have some Perl code which is executed in a context where all command line arguments, inputs and outputs are encoded in the encoding given by the `LC_CTYPE` environment variable (or more generally the `LC_CTYPE` setting determined from the environment). This is exactly what [`use locale`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#The-use-locale-pragma) is for, right?

```
$ echo àé | perl -e 'use locale; print uc <>'
ÀÉ
```

This works in unibyte locales such as Latin-1, but not in UTF-8, where this program outputs `àé` on my Debian wheezy machine.

`perl -CLADS -e 'use locale; print uc <>'` seems to do the right thing in unibyte locales and UTF-8, at least according to my understanding of the [documentation of `-C`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-%5b_number%2flist_%5d*). I don't understand how I'm supposed to deduce that from the [`perllocale` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#Unicode-and-UTF-8) though, nor what would happen in multibyte locales other than UTF-8.

Furthermore I actually don't want to run the whole program in this mode, only one code block. In fact **I can't pass parameters to the Perl interpreter**, I can only pass a string to a Perl script which calls `eval` on that string. `use locale`'s local scope would be just fine, but how do I activate `-C` from within?

> The read-only magic variable `${^UNICODE}`

… so not that then.

How do I run a snippet of Perl code in a mode where all strings (including `@ARGV` and file input/output) are interpreted according to the locale indicated by the environment?

Comment: One citation:  [perldelta v5.20(!)](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.20.0/perldelta.html#use-locale-now-works-on-UTF-8-locales). _Until this release, only single-byte locales, such as the ISO 8859 series were supported. Now, the increasingly common multi-byte UTF-8 locales are also supported. A UTF-8 locale is one in which the character set is Unicode and the encoding is UTF-8._

Answer (score 4):

It seems like [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-C-[_number/list_]*) explains that -C is a combination of [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) and [use open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html);, so this will probably work (on *nix)

update: decoding @ARGV with a little help from open.pm :)

```
{
    use Encode();
    require encoding;
    local @ARGV = @ARGV ;
    if( my $locale_encoding = encoding::_get_locale_encoding() ){
        $locale_encoding = ":encoding($locale_encoding)";
        @ARGV = map { Encode::decode($locale_encoding, $_ ) } @ARGV;
    }
    use open ':locale';
    use locale;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start, it works for `echo àé | perl -e 'use locale; print uc <>'`, but it's evidently not enough: it breaks `perl -le 'use locale; use open qw(:locale); print uc($ARGV[0])' é` which prints `Ã©`: somehow `use open qw(:locale)` seems to cause the UTF-8 argument to be interpreted as latin1!

Comment: yes, locale/open dont touch @ARGV, that you have to do yourself, see update (which will be updated again)